# Matplotlib tripcolor bug?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, triangulation

I want to use tripcolor from matplotlib.pyplot to view the colored contours of some of my data.

The data is extracted from an XY plane at z=cst using Paraview. I directly export the data in csv from Paraview which triangulates the plane for me.

The problem is that depending on the plane position (ie the mesh) tripcolor gives me sometimes good or bad results.

Here is a simple example code and results to illustrate it:

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

p,u,v,w,x,y,z  = np.loadtxt('./bad.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),unpack=True)

NbLevels = 256

plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

plt.tripcolor(x,y,w,NbLevels,cmap=plt.cm.hot_r,edgecolor='black')

cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Velocity magnitude',labelpad=10)

plt.show()
```

**Results with tripcolor**

[image]

Here is the [file](http://dl.free.fr/ggxUYIc7M) that causes the problem.

I've heard that  matplotlib's tripcolor is sometimes buggy, so is it a bug or not ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As highlighted by @Hooked this is the normal behaviour for a Delaunay triangulation.
To remove unwanted triangles you should provide your own `Triangulation` by passing explicitly the triangles.

This is quite easy in your case as your data is almost structured: I suggest performing a Delaunay triangulation in the plane (r, theta) then passing these triangles to the initial (x, y) arrays. You can make use of the the built-in `TriAnalyzer` class to remove very *flat* triangles from the (r, theta) triangulation (they might exists due to round-off errors).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.tri as mtri

p,u,v,w,x,y,z  = np.loadtxt('./bad.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),unpack=True)

r = np.sqrt(y**2 + x**2)
tan = (y / x)
aux_tri = mtri.Triangulation(r/np.max(r), tan/np.max(tan))
triang = mtri.Triangulation(x, y, aux_tri.triangles)
triang.set_mask(mtri.TriAnalyzer(aux_tri).get_flat_tri_mask())

NbLevels = 256

plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

plt.tripcolor(triang, w, NbLevels, cmap=plt.cm.jet, edgecolor='black')

cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Velocity magnitude',labelpad=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Ragloo Make sure you upvote good answers and accept this one if it completes your question!

Comment: @Hooked thanks for the advice, unfortunately I've got less than 15 reputations so I can't upvote answer for the moment

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because the [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) called by Paraview created a convex hull of the points (as it should). To test this, I used `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation` and plotted the resulting mesh from the x-y values:

```
import matplotlib.tri as tri
plt.scatter(x,y)
w[:] = 1
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
plt.tripcolor(triang,w,alpha=.2)
```

[image]

which shows the same effect. It may be possible to remove the unwanted triangles from the mesh, either by hand, or using a non-convex boundary finder.

Comment: Thanks Hooked for the advice and for including the image in my question it's way nicer :)